# ¿Alguien sabe cómo colocar una variable en un ArrayList al hacer print?

Tags: java

`users` es el `ArrayList` y quiero colocar una `int` para que haga una impresión de lo que exista en esa posición.

```
int x;
```

Algo como users[x]

```
System.out.println(users);
```

Comment: ¿users es un array de valores enteros?

Answer (score 2):

En el caso de un [**ArrayList**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html),

Suponiendo que tu ArrayList almacena valores tipo int:

```
users = new ArrayList<int>();
```

Para agregar un elemento dentro del ArrayList, usa el método [**add( )**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-)

```
//Agrega el valor de 12
users.add(12);
```

Para acceder a un elemento dentro del ArrayList, usa el método [**get( )**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) definiendo el indice del elemento, recuerda que el primer elemento tiene el indice 0.

Por lo tanto si deseas imprimir el primer elemento, lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
System.out.println(users.get(0));
```

Es buena practica validar también cuando existen elementos en tu ArrayList mediante el método [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty--)

```
  if(users.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("No existen elementos");
  }else{
    //Imprime elementos.
    for(int u : users){
      System.out.println(u);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si `users` es un ArrayList, para ver lo que contiene en la posición `i` debes usar el método get: `users.get(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tienes algo como:

```
List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

En esta List almacenas los nombres de los usuarios, y de entrada quieres pasar un entero con la posicion del usuario que deseas,

```
int indice = 2;
String usuario = users.get(indice);
```

Con el codigo anterior puedes obtener el usuario que esta en la posicion 2 de la lista.